# Let $V$ be a set of irrational real numbers with normal $+$, $*$. Is $V$ a vector space or not?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a set of irrational real numbers with normal $+$, $*$. Is $V$ a vector space or not?

is there a simple explanation? do we have to use all the $10$ axioms to prove this.

Comment: Is it the case that for all $x,y \in \mathbb R - \mathbb Q$ that $x+y \in \mathbb R - \mathbb Q$?  i.e is your set closed under addition?

Answer (score 5):

A vector space must contain the zero vector and since zero is rational the irrationals cannot be a vector space.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use all the axioms to prove it is a vector space (if it were), but it would be enough to show that one of them is not true to show that it is not.

Hint: it is not a vector space. If it were, it would be a subspace of $\mathbb R$ (because is a subset an $\mathbb R$ is itself a vector space). So it should verify the three properties of a subspace. Try to see which one/s fail?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist that all the numbers be irrational it is not.  There are no identities for addition and multiplication.